# JQuery Cycle plugin displaying the wrong images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, cycle

Oh great forum,

Please help!! I am having a problem with the basic JQuery Cycle plugin where I have defined classes for 3 indevidual divs inside a parent/wrapper div. Each div has 3 images inside which are specific to their respective parents. The problem is that the JQuery Cycle plugin is displaying the images in the wrong divs!! It would be great if someone could provide a solution for me and an explanation as to why this is happening. If it makes a difference I am working in Wordpress. Here is the html:

```
<div class="gateway_img_containers clearfix">
    <div class="left_gateway_img_holder">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position1_img_left.jpg" />
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position2_img_left.jpg" />
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position3_img_left.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="middle_gateway_img_holder">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position2_img_left.jpg" />
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position_2_img_middle.jpg" />
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position_2_img_right.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="right_gateway_img_holder">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position3_img_left.jpg" />
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position_3_img_middle.jpg" />
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/position_3_img_right.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.left_gateway_img_holder').cycle();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.middle_gateway_img_holder').cycle();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.right_gateway_img_holder').cycle();
    });
</script>
```

Can I restrict which images display by specifying them inside the the cycle()?

Let me know if you need more info! thankx :)

Comment: Are you sure your paths are correct? I see that you're probably missing `_` here `/images/position2_img_left.jpg` and here `/images/position3_img_left.jpg`...

Comment: paths are correct... just inconsistent hehe. My bad :S Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.left_gateway_img_holder').cycle();
        $j('.middle_gateway_img_holder').cycle();
        $j('.right_gateway_img_holder').cycle();
    });
</script>
```

You don't need to write different ready functions, try to add relative position and hidden overflow to all your divs